# MySQL - Correct way and performance about some table

Tags: mysql, sql, performance

I'm a bit confused about the better way to do it, well i have these table:

## country

```
CREATE TABLE `country` (
  `country_id` int(11) NOT NULL auto_increment,
  `country_name` varchar(2) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY  (`estado_id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

## state

```
CREATE TABLE `state` (
  `state_id` int(11) NOT NULL auto_increment,
  `state_name` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
  `country_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY  (`state_id`),
  KEY `tc001_ix` (`county_id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

ALTER TABLE `state`
  ADD CONSTRAINT `tc001_ix` FOREIGN KEY (`county_id`) REFERENCES `county` (`county_id`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE;
```

## city

```
CREATE TABLE `city` (
  `city_id` int(11) NOT NULL auto_increment,
  `city_name` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
  `state_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY  (`city_id`),
  KEY `tc002_ix` (`state_id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

ALTER TABLE `city`
  ADD CONSTRAINT `tc002_ix` FOREIGN KEY (`state_id`) REFERENCES `state` (`state_id`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE;
```

## location

```
CREATE TABLE `location` (
  `location_id` int(11) NOT NULL auto_increment,
  `location_field01` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  `location_field02` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  `city_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY  (`location_id`),
  KEY `ta001_ix` (`city_id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT charset utf8;

ALTER TABLE `tb_location`
  ADD CONSTRAINT `ta001_ix` FOREIGN KEY (`city_id`) REFERENCES `city` (`city_id`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE;
```

When I will run a query on the Location table by State, should I put a foreign key `country_id` in Location table or in the query I should do an inner join in Cities table then State table? I will have filters that can filter by the City too.

I would like to now what is the correct way and what has a better performance:

- **1 foreign key** `city_id` or
- **2 foreign keys** `city_id` and `state_id`.

Thanks.

Comment: You have a typo: `county_id` should be `country_id`.

Comment: The way you have it is the most normalized, but it might not be great for performance. You'll have to see whether it causes performance problems in your application.

Comment: What's best depends on how you're using the data. If you need to create a menu of all the cities in a state or all the states in a country, or validate that a state input is correct for the country, this design is perfect. If you're just storing city/state/country information for a location, it might be overkill.

Comment: if you show us a query we can tell you what indexes will make it faster.  We can't guess without some actual sql code.

Comment: @Barmar i wrote it wrong sry ;p

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should first things first have a normalized database design without duplicate data stored.

As you have it now, it says:

> Each Country has its States. Each State has its Cities. Each City has
>   its Locations.

This type of relation is called Composition in UML language. With this design *you cannot have a location outside the City or a Country without States*, and that is the principal question you should ask: is that OK, is that what I want?

If you add `State_Id` to `Location` table, you de-normalize your database. This is something advisable only when you are already experiencing big performance problems or something like that.

Location with `City_ID = NULL` and `State_Id = XXX` could mean a Location outside any City, but when all your Locations are inside Cities, then there is no need to add `State_ID` to `Location` table.

So you should not probably add `State_ID` to `Locations` table. **Do not duplicate your data and do not de-normalize the database without very strong reasons.** Use JOINs and other SQL commands to get data form related tables.

You should draw a class or db diagram, if you are not sure about how you should structure your tables.

[image]

Comment: Nice explain thanks, Well my main concern is about  when location table get bigger, doing a query like: select .. from location a inner join city b on b.city_id=a.city_id inner join state c on c.state_id=b.state_id where c.state_id=X order by a.location_field01 asc, if location has about 5000 records and city about 2000 and state about 500, this query could get slower? i thought maybe doing a reverse query could be better like: select ... from state a inner join city b on a.state_id=b.state_id inner join location c on b.city_id=c.city_id where a.state_id=X order by c.location_field01 asc.

Comment: @JessicaBelao Both queries you wrote **are identical in terms of performace**, both have the same execution plan. With INNER JOIN it does not matter which table is on the left and which is on the right. JOINS perform really fast in relational databases, so you are supposed to use them. 5000 locations is really very few, 50 millions could be a problem. If you want to say thanks here on SO, use upvote button.

Answer (score 0):

What is the purpose of your Location table? I think the best way to do that is using INNER JOIN (States with Cities). Logically, a city belongs to one state (regardless of whether a city is repeated in another state). Your City table could have a FK pointing to your State table. Then, you just need one FK.

By the way, check your script (you wrote "county" instead of "country").

The follow script it's similar to yours, but in MSSQL and without a Country table (make the necessary changes):

```
IF NOT EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM sys.tables WHERE name = 'States')
CREATE TABLE States(
    IdState     TINYINT IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    StateName   VARCHAR(35) NULL,
    CONSTRAINT  PK_States PRIMARY KEY(IdState)
)

IF NOT EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM sys.tables WHERE name = 'Cities')
CREATE TABLE Cities(
    IdCity      SMALLINT IDENTITY(1, 1) NOT NULL,
    CityName    VARCHAR(100) NULL,
    IdState     TINYINT NULL,
    CONSTRAINT  PK_Cities PRIMARY KEY(IdCity),
    CONSTRAINT  FK_Cities_States FOREIGN KEY(IdState) REFERENCES States(IdState)
)
```

Hope this helps!